# Як правильно вживати вислів “за вимогою”, “по вимозі”, “на вимогу”?

Tags: вживання-слів, прийменники

Досить часто, в маршрутці пасажири просять зупинити водія на зупинці "[за вимогою](https://krmisto.gov.ua/ua/transtops/detail/id/428.html)" або "[по вимозі](https://krmisto.gov.ua/ua/transtops/detail/id/517.html)", або ж взагалі "на вимогу". То який вислів вірніше вживати в даному випадку?

"Словопедія" [вказує](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53407/26657.html) в [обох](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53399/26755.html) випадках що:

> правильніше: на вимогу

"rozum.org.ua" теж [наполягає](http://rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=25&t=6693) на використанні сполучення:

> На вимогу

"Лайфхаки з української мови" в розділі "Типові помилки в словосполученнях і реченнях" теж [зазначає](https://ukr-lifehacks.ed-era.com/13lec/tipovi_pomilki.html), що вірним буде:

> **Помилкове вживання - Правильне вживання**
>   зупинка по вимозі - зупинка на вимогу

Отже який вислів є вірним: "на вимогу", "по вимозі", "за вимогою"?
В яких випадках які вислови з наведених вживати доречніше?

Answer (score 6):

Довідник українського слововживання М.Волощак [Неправильно-Правильно](http://nepravylno-pravylno.wikidot.com/pryimennyky)

> За вимогою контролерів ― На вимогу контролерів

СУМ-20

> ***[ВИМОГА](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=9669&page=334)*** 1. Наполегливі побажання, прохання, виражені в
> категоричній формі.
>
> ***Висува́ти / ви́сунути вимо́гу*** див. висува́ти; (1) ***На вимо́гу*** – відповідно до чийого-небудь прохання, наказу і т. ін. *Я пройшов наперед, до водія, і прошу його спинити машину на зупинці, де автобус спиняється тільки на вимогу* (Б. Антоненко-Давидович); *На вимогу комбата артилерійський підтримуючий полк вислав дві самохідні гармати* (О. Гончар); *Апостиль проставляється на вимогу особи, яка підписала документ, або будь-якого пред'явника документа* (з мови документів).

Єдиний правильний варіант — ***на вимогу***